# Use mod_rewrite to create custom directory index in Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, directory-listing, mod-autoindex

So, Apache's default directory listing sucks and mod_autoindex's customisation options suck, so I figured I could write some rewrite rules in my server root to redirect any requests to a directory:

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule .* /index.php?dir=$0
</IfModule>
```

Now, I get the impression this works at least a little, as turning off `indexes` still leaves `localhost` accessible (it displays the index.php), however it doesn't seem to reach subdirectories (which either revert to Apache's directory indexes if the `indexes` option is on, or give a `403` if they're off).

My question is: can I get this rule to apply globally or is my quest for pretty directory indexes doomed to failure?

**Edit**: I should note: the above rules are contained in a `.htaccess` in the server root.

**Edit**: Ideally the solution, if it exists, would still have `DirectoryIndex` functionality (that is, `index.php` etc. will be displayed if it exists),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-d` directory test does only work with absolute file system paths. So either provide an absolute file system path (e.g. by using `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}` or `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` directly) or use `-D` that makes an additional subrequest to resolve the URI path to a file system path. I’d prefer:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* /index.php?dir=$0
```

Comment: Wow, I'm a tool.  Thanks for catching this!